why is there the need for a reduction between clique and multicoloured clique?
I do not understand why we need to make a reduction from k-clique to k-multicoloured clique.
Any k-clique can only be coloured in k different colours since each pair of vertices is adjacent. So it already induces a k-colouring.
What am I missing?
Thanks!

This question is incomprehensible without context. Who, where, is making a reduction from $k$-clique to $k$-multicoloured clique?

I am reading a course at university about parametrised algorithms. On the slides they talk about an FTP reduction from clique to k-colouring. They clone every node within the graph k times one for each colour and add edges between nodes that are adjacent in the original graph and of different colour in the new cloned graph. I do not know if I missed something.

The main point of considering the Multicolored Clique problem is that the input of Multicolored Clique already comes with a $k$-coloring which facilitates parameterized reductions to other problems. For example, one may assume then that the maximum clique size does not exceed $k$ and that the size-$k$ clique, if it exists, contains exactly one vertex from each color class.
Now concerning the necessity of providing a reduction from Clique to Multicolored Clique: Yes, the clique number $k$ is a lower bound on the coloring number but they are not necessarily the same. So a priori, it could still be the case that Clique is W[1]-hard with respect to the clique size $k$ in general but FPT with respect to $k$ in $k$-colorable graphs. The reduction shows that the latter case is also W[1]-hard.
